# Xamarin: Unable to build after updating NuGet Package: Xamarin.Build.DownloadsAaRProgGuard failed

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin

In my app I now have this issue upon building:

`The "Xamarin.Build.Download.XamarinBuildAndroidAarProguardConfigs" task could not be loaded from the assembly C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\xxx oud\packages\Xamarin.Build.Download.0.4.6\build\Xamarin.Build.Download.dll.  Confirm that the <UsingTask> declaration is correct, that the assembly and all its dependencies are available, and that the task contains a public class that implements Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask.`

I've read in the forum from many users that just restarting Visual Studio would fix this. Other suggested changing the Xamarin.Build.Download package.

Well, just restarting does nothing and changing the package is not possible, because other packages seem to depend on this. So just remove those to? I cannot, because those packages somehow depend on the first package so it just goes back and forth.

All I did yesterday was download the Facebook SDK from NuGet and even though I deinstalled it again, I cannot build - always with the above error.

Comment: What is your verson of `Xamarin.Build.Download`? Try to upload your VS, `.net framework` and `android support repository` to the lastest version. In the end, close the project, delete the `bin` and `obj` folder, open your VS to bulid the project.

Comment: hello. I have the newest .net framework and the newest support repository installed. my xamarin.build.download is 0.4.11 (which nuget calls the "newest version"). i deleted both folders and restartet VS. it immediately crashed again with the same error. the only way I get it to build is to disable all nuget packages and then reenable them one by one. upon enableing the facebook ads sdk, the error reappears ... it is super annoying -.-

Comment: Also, I can only change xamarin.build.download when I delte all google ads addons beforehand. after i do so, I can delete xamarin.build.download and everything works "fine" again. Now I only download the facebook SDK and everything reappears. The google things do, and the xamarin,build.download too. and this crashes the whole project then again